# I am trying to find a book (young adult) where the devil is the protaganist, and other gods appear as characters

Tags: story-identification, books

I believe it was written by a teenager, and might have a sequel.

It has been many years since I read it, but I believe it had the devil acting like a regular human. He wasn't evil. I think it incorporated a lot of (gods/characters) norse, roman, Christian, and pagan.

Comment: Can you provide any other details? Any particular mythology of gods? And did it have the word "Time" in the title, do you think, or did it have a word relating to time in the title?

Comment: It has been many years since I read it, but I believe it had the devil acting like a regular human.  He wasn't evil.   I think it incorporated a lot of (gods/characters) norse, roman, Christian, and pagan.   It is possible it was a word related to time in the title.

Comment: You might take a look through http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_books_written_by_children_or_teenagers and see if any of the titles look right to you. I don't see anything involving time except for ''Timekeepers'', published in 2002, which seems too recent.

Comment: thank you Sean Duggan I found it.  It is Waywalkers by Catherine Webb,   Timekeepers was the sequel.

Comment: Ah. Go ahead and add that as an answer, along with what parts of it match up with your query (optimally, removing parts of your question which you misremembered and don't match, and adding other pertinent details), then accept it. :) That way, others might benefit.

Comment: @user276415, the answer you added, should be added as an answer, below the question.

Comment: I can't I havn't been a user long enough and don't have the reputation points.   The answer is a couple comments up.

Comment: @user276415 Right below the comments, don't you see a white box that says 'Your Answer' ? You can write your answer there

Comment: All users have enough rep to post an answer. You just won't be able to accept it for a day or two.

Comment: You can accept it tomorrow and likely get some rep from upvotes in the mean-time. :)

Answer (score 7):

Thanks to the link Sean Duggan suggested, I was able to find out that the book was *[Waywalkers](https://www.fantasticfiction.com/w/catherine-webb/waywalkers.htm)* by Catherine Webb.

[image: Waywalkers - Book Cover]

> Sam Linnfer works part time at a London University. He's a quiet chap. A few friends here and there. A real skill for ancient languages. And an affection for cats. He's also immortal and the Son of Time. You might know him better as Lucifer, Old Nick, or the Devil . And with all the Gods in Heaven about to go to war over ownership of Earth, you're going to be extremely glad he's not exactly the person history portrays him to be. Waywalkers is an absolutely stunning new novel. You'll come face to face with Jehovah on a cold Moscow night, walk the Ways between Earth and Heaven with Buddha, take a hair-raising cab ride with Adam (yes, THE Adam - only he's into denim now, rather than fig-leaves) and find yourself trusting the one person you never dreamed you would. In a war between Gods, where Earth is the battle ground and humans are expendable, you'll need to have more than just sympathy for the Devil.

Comment: If you enjoyed that you might enjoy [Piers Anthony's Incarnations of Immortality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incarnations_of_Immortality) series (be warned it's rather silly in places)

Comment: @AakashM That was the series I was thinking of as well.